# What exactly are the boundaries between Android's Density Buckets?

Tags: android, android-screen-support, android-screen

I want to categorize our inventory of Android development devices by screen density bucket.

I easily discovered the physical densities for each device in PPI units. This is standard information given as part of product specs.

However, given the PPI number, how can I confidently categorize each device into a density bucket? The [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range) gives a **simple number** for the density buckets, along with [a diagram](http://developer.android.com/images/screens_support/screens-ranges.png) showing approximate and overlapping ranges.

For example, consider a device that has a screen density of 370 PPI. Android's XHDPI bucket is "~320", while the XXHDPI bucket is "~420". So which bucket does 370 fall into?

I've been unable to find a precise specification of where the boundaries are between the buckets; or, if they overlap, exactly how large the overlap is. Is this subjective? Do I really need to run test software on each physical device to determine the bucket?

Comment: I'm surprised this question hasn't been answered yet. The fact that it has so few votes suggests that the question itself isn't that important, but I am not sure why. Having the same question myself.

Comment: You don't need PPI. If you just want to know what screen density bucket each of your development devices are, you could get it by ```Timber.i("Device dpi is ${resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi}")``` in your application class. You can just run this line once on every device and check which bucket it is under. https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities#TaskUseDP

Will this solve your need, or you just interested in the underlying theory?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the specific density bucket a device falls into is determined by the manufacturer, and does not follow a strict formula.

I imagine that this determination takes into account effective screen density as well as the # pixels and the physical dimensions of the device, so that the "bucket" that is selected produces the best results both from an asset size and a layout perspective.